# pass parameters to insided functions

Tags: julia

Suppose I have a very simple function,

```
function func_in(x; y, z)
    println(x + z)
end
```

which is called by another function

```
function test_dict(x, y, z...)
    println(x + y )
    func_in(z...)
end
```

I would like to pass parameter in `z...` to `func_in`. How could I do it in the right way? Note in `func_in` there are kargs and I could not find a way to pass parameter correctly.

The following code doesn't work

```
test_dict(1, 2, 15, 17, 19)
```

Many thanks!

**UPDATE**

I would like to be a little more elaborate about possible scenarios that parameters in `z...` could be very flexible.

```
function func_in(x; y, z, t1, t2, t3, t4)
    println(x + t4)
end
```

Then how do I only pass x and t4, something like:

```
test_dict(1, 2, (x = 15, t4 = 19))
```

In `R` language, the `...` works straightforwardly. Anything in `...` would be used when it is cited. Like following, `...` is directly passed to fn_2 and depatached accordingly. How to get similar behivor in `Julia`? I hope I have made myself clear.

```
fn_1 <- function(x, y, ...) {
   fn_2(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positional args and kwargs must be splatted separately:

```
func_in(args...; kwargs...)
```

Right now, you only pass positional inputs.

If you want to only pass kwargs to a function, you must do (note leading `;`)

```
foo(; kwargs...)
```

BTW, it is considered good practice to always distinguish kwargs with a leading `;`, even when it is not strictly necessary:

```
foo(x, y, a="hello", b=4)  # legal
foo(x, y; a="hello", b=4)  # better style
foo(a="hello", b=4)  # legal
foo(; a="hello", b=4)  # better style
```

**Response to update:** Keyword arguments must either have a default value, or you must provide a value for it when you call the function. You can for example write:

```
function func_in(x; y=nothing, z=nothing, t1=nothing, t2=nothing, t3=nothing, t4=nothing)
```

Another problem in your function `test_dict`, is that you must call it with *three* positional arguments, two for `println` and one for `func_in`, but you are only calling it with two positional arguments.

This will work:

```
function func_in(x; y=nothing, z=nothing, t1=nothing, t2=nothing, t3=nothing, t4=nothing)
    println(x + t4)
end

function test_dict(x, y, z; w...) # note: *three* positional args
    println(x + y )
    func_in(z; w...)
end

test_dict(1, 2, 3; y = 15, t4 = 19)  # three positional args
```

You can also use a named tuple and splat it:

```
kwargs = (y = 15, t4 = 19)  # named tuple
test_dict(1, 2, 3; kwargs...)
```

Comment: Thanks! The inside functions could be more completed with both positional args and kwargs. How to write the codes? Basically I would like to get the similar behivor of ... in R.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I might understand the para passing better in Julia. If I got it correctly, it is not possible to pass both position and kargs with w...? i.e. func_in(w...) instead of func_in(z; w...), as func_in has one position arg?

Comment: Yes, the central point is that keyword splitting must occur after a `;`. For example: `foo(; kwargs...)` will work, and `foo(kwargs...)` will not.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you have in mind? :

```
julia> function func_in(x; y, z)
           println(x + z)
       end
func_in (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function test_dict(x, y, z...)
           println(x + y )
           func_in(z[1]; y = z[2], z = z[3])
       end
test_dict (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test_dict(1, 2, 15, 17, 19)
3
34
```

Comment: Thanks for the working solution! How to handle situations where z... is not the same length as func_in? I have updated my question.